# python store data from file to variables

Tags: python

I’m new to python and I’m taking my first steps to create some scripts. 
I want to access a file and store the items into a list and access each item as its own variable. 
The format of the file is .txt and it’s as such but not limited to 3 columns it could be 4 or more.

```
textData,1

textData,2

textData,3,moreData

textData,4,moreData4

textData,5
```

I know how to read and append to a list and access individual items starting with [0] but when I do that I get textData, 1  for [0] and I only want textData on its own and 1 on its own and so on as I loop through the file.

Below is my start of this:

```
file = open('fileName','r')

list = []

for items in file:

  list.append(items)

print(list[0])
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and provide direction.

Comment: as an aside, don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the lines:

```
my_list = []
for lines in file:
    my_list.append(lines.split(','))

print(my_list)
```

Comment: please don't use `list` as a variable.

Comment: You are right. I have just taken the authors variable names. I should have use more sensible ones and not one that shadows a datatype. I have corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over a file object, you get each line as a `str`. You can then get each word by using the `.split` method, which returns a list of `str`s. As your items are comma-separated, we split on `','`. We do not want to `append` this list to the overall list, but rather add all elements of the list to the overall list, hence the `+=`:

```
file = open('fileName', 'r')
mylist = []
for line in file:
    words = line.split(',')
    mylist += words
print(mylist[0])
```

Also, avoid using `list` as a variable name, as this is the name of the builtin `list` function.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply but I still get textData,1 and I just want TextData for [0] and 1 for [1]

Comment: This worked and thank you. Now I need to study what you did and understand it.

Comment: Indeed. If you are satisfied, please accept it as *the* answer. :-)